# Find an algorithm to dynamically optimize the size of the queue

Tags: algorithm, optimization, mathematical-optimization, capacity, inventory-management

Current state of the world.

- I have a fixed size Queue of items.
- Consumers get items from the Queue at different rates. It changes overtime, I.e 10 request by minute , tomorrow it can be 20 request by minute and so on. It changes overtime.
- Items are put on the Queue to keep up with the desired size of the Queue.
- The rate of putting items into the queue is also not constant overtime. It can vary.

Problem:

- find the a size of a queue that ensures that queue are not empty.

With a fixed size queue, we would need to keep a huge size of queue so that the changes to dry out the queue are reduced

So a better approach would be to dynamically change the size of the queue, so that based on the rate of consumers and the rate of producers we find an optimal size of a queue such as:

- We avoid running out it items on the Queue
- We avoid keeping a waste of items by keeping lot of items on the queue.
- Maybe the ideal size is keeping the Queue 25% from getting empty.

Comment: You say "Items are put on the Queue to keep up with the desired size of the Queue", but *how responsive* is this?  In other words, if the queue goes below the desired level, how long does it take before the supply-service notices and adds more (or increases its feed rate)?

Comment: This is basically a cost-benefit problem, to answer it we need to know things like: what is the cost of having 1 item on the queue for 1 minute, vs the cost of having a request for 1 item going unserved for 1 minute?  We also need to know some things about the variability of the request-rate.  For instance what is the average  *and variance* of the daily request-rate.  Most important would be to know the request-rate average and variance wrt the response-time of the supply-service.